empty list with method reference cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException【resolved】
update
groovy 3.0.20 resolved the bug.
if arguments is ListParam,will transform argument to get(0) element
    private MetaMethod tryListParamMetaMethod(Class sender, String methodName, boolean isCallToSuper, Object[] arguments) {
        MetaMethod method = null;
        if (arguments.length == 1 && arguments[0] instanceof List) {
            Object[] newArguments = ((List)arguments[0]).toArray();
            method = this.createTransformMetaMethod(this.getMethodWithCaching(sender, methodName, newArguments, isCallToSuper));
        }

        return method;
    }

    protected MetaMethod createTransformMetaMethod(MetaMethod method) {
        return method == null ? null : new TransformMetaMethod(method) {
            public Object invoke(Object object, Object[] arguments) {
                Object firstArgument = arguments[0];
                List list = (List)firstArgument;
                arguments = list.toArray();
                return super.invoke(object, arguments);
            }
        };
    }


my evniment:
groovy 3.0.8
jvm 1.8
test case code
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
if the param List not empty, the code is running normally
static void main(String[] args) {
         Closure methodClosure = List::size //  or List.&size
         List param = new ArrayList()         
         methodClosure.call(param)     
} 

Problem troubleshooting
I want to use Java stream in Groovy code to retrieve the size of a list, but an exception is thrown when the list is empty.
Next, I will debug and find that for lambda, it will be compiled into a MethodClosure, and the 'onwer' of this MethodClosure is' List. class'.
As shown in the following code, tryListParamMetaMethod obtains an empty List from the parameters, so it attempts to obtain the method without parameters and discovers the size method of the List.
But the parameters did not match during the call, so an error was reported.
see groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.class
private Object invokeMethodClosure(Object object, Object[] arguments) {
        final MethodClosure mc = (MethodClosure) object;
        final Object owner = mc.getOwner();

        String methodName = mc.getMethod();
        final Class ownerClass = owner instanceof Class ? (Class) owner : owner.getClass();
        final MetaClass ownerMetaClass = registry.getMetaClass(ownerClass);

        // To conform to "Least Surprise" principle, try to invoke method with original arguments first, which can match most of use cases
        try {

// debug this ownerMetaClass is 'List.class'
            return ownerMetaClass.invokeMethod(ownerClass, owner, methodName, arguments, false, false);
        } catch (MissingMethodExceptionNoStack | InvokerInvocationException e) {
            // CONSTRUCTOR REFERENCE
            if (owner instanceof Class && MethodClosure.NEW.equals(methodName)) {
                if (ownerClass.isArray()) {
     
....


private MetaMethod getMetaMethod(Class sender, Object object, String methodName, boolean isCallToSuper, Object... arguments) {
        MetaMethod method = null;
        if (CALL_METHOD.equals(methodName) && object instanceof GeneratedClosure) {
            method = getMethodWithCaching(sender, DO_CALL_METHOD, arguments, isCallToSuper);
        }
        if (method == null) {
            method = getMethodWithCaching(sender, methodName, arguments, isCallToSuper);
        }
        MetaClassHelper.unwrap(arguments);

        if (method == null)
//debug code runing this, list arguments will test get first element to find method
            method = tryListParamMetaMethod(sender, methodName, isCallToSuper, arguments);
        return method;
    }



private MetaMethod tryListParamMetaMethod(Class sender, String methodName, boolean isCallToSuper, Object[] arguments) {
        MetaMethod method = null;
        if (arguments.length == 1 && arguments[0] instanceof List) {
            Object[] newArguments = ((List) arguments[0]).toArray();
            method = createTransformMetaMethod(getMethodWithCaching(sender, methodName, newArguments, isCallToSuper));
        }
        return method;
    }


For the records: works with Groovy Version: 4.0.19 JVM: 21.0.2

According to the web console it works with groovy 3.0.20 as well

Can confirm for 3.0.8 - so maybe a bug. Update to 3.0.21?
